# Random String Generator is returning same values

Tags: php

```
$list_ar = array();
for($x = 0;$x < 500; $x++){
    $val = generateRandomString(20);
    if(!in_array($val,$list_ar)){
        echo $x.'=='.$val.'<br>';
        array_push($list_ar,$val);
    } else {
        echo $x.'== IN ARRAY<br>';
    }
}

function generateRandomString($length){
    $characterlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';
    $characterlist_array = str_split($characterlist);
    $id = '';
    for($a = 0;$a<$length;$a++){
        shuffle($characterlist_array);
        $position = array_rand($characterlist_array, 1);
        $id .= $characterlist_array[$position];
    }
    return $id; 
}
```

When I run the code above it gives **`in array false`** up to **`360 lines`** after that it returns **`in array true`**. I'm expecting it to return in array false up to **`500 lines`** I've been running the code more than 20 times and it gives the same result of exactly **`360 lines in array false`**. Any ideas?

Comment: this code is HIGHLY ineffcient... why are you shuffling the entire charlist array, when you could just be generating a random INDEX key to lookup a char in that array? it's far easier generating a SINGLE ranumber number, e.g. `$id .= $characterlist[rand(0,count($characterlist)-1)]` than is to completely shuffle the array and then generate a random number to generate the key.

Comment: I don't get `in array` any times: http://codepad.org/7kRUTLRy

Comment: changed my code and based it on @MarcB suggestion and it worked. thanks!

Comment: There's a comment in the docs for `array_rand` here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php#105265 That indicates that it has very strange randomness behavior (like, it might not actually be particularly random at all).  I tried a couple of different ideas, and as long as I don't call that function, I can make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Marc said what happens if you change your function to:

```
function generateRandomString($length){
    $characterlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';
    $characterlist_count = strlen($characterlist)-1;

    $id = '';
    for($a = 0;$a<$length;$a++){
        $id .= $characterlist[rand(0,$characterlist_count)];
    }
    return $id; 
}
```

Does it still fail?

Comment: note that `count(string) - 1` always returns 0.  You still need the `str_split`

Answer (score 0):

Since we are answering with alternatives:

```
function generateRandomString($length) {
    $characterlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';
    $characterlist_array = str_split($characterlist);
    shuffle($characterlist_array);

    return implode(array_slice($characterlist_array, 0, $length));
}
```